# How to change First Weekday of Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Date calendar?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I would like to change the first day of week in Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Service 2008 R2 Date calendar.

This issue was found in SSRS 2005 and it should not be in SSRS 2008 R2.

Right Now the WeekDays are starting from Sunday - Saturday. I would like to Change it from Saturday-Friday.

Please check the Calendar for the month:  June 2012.

Right Now Date Calendar is in below manner: Sunday - Saturday

S | M | T | W | T | F | S

I want in Below Manner: Saturday - Friday

S | S | M | T | W | T | F

I checked Microsoft Website for solution and this was issue in Micorosf SQL Server Reporting 2005.

Please help me over this.

Many Thansk & Regards

Sikander

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for changing the first day. It might not answer your question, but could be helpful [@@DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

The `SET DATEFIRST 5` will only change it for that session. Also, you will probably loose the change if the server/service is restarted. You could work around this by using the `SET DATEFIRST` inside your reports.

Comment: Hi, I tried this too. I thought might changing SQL Server DateFirst will affect it but didn't helped. I also changed Regional Settings and Set Saturday as Day First but didn't worked too.

Comment: @SikanderMandal: What is the message that you get after executing `SET DATEFIRST 6;` command? Also, please provide your sql query.

Comment: Hi the query is below and after execution. I ran report but Calendar is still starting from Sunday to Saturday.

Set Datefirst 5
Select @@Datefirst
Select datename(w,@@Datefirst)

Many Thanks!

Comment: @SikanderMandal: The `SET DATEFIRST` value is not persisted. Check the updated answer.